# Own nav path has closed loop in rviz

Tags: navigation, pose, path, ros-kinetic, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to make simple path following for differential drive robot,

So, I generated nav.msg/Path with own points and publish it, but in rviz I see my path with connection between start and end points, but I want see just my arc.
[image: my own publisher]

When I use the code from [Publisher about trajectory path](https://answers.ros.org/question/278616/how-to-create-a-publisher-about-trajectory-path-then-show-it-in-rviz/?answer=278629#post-id-278629) to generate path from odom topic to path topic, I see not closed trajectory, that what I want to generate in my own path publisher.
[image: odom to path]

What is my mistake?

How publish own points like nav.msg/Path correctly?

My source of publish node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy

from nav_msgs.msg import Path
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose

path = Path()
path.header.frame_id = 'odom'
seq = 0

def cartesian_to_path(x, y):
    global seq
    path.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()

    for i, xi in enumerate(x):
        pose = PoseStamped()
        pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        pose.header.frame_id = 'odom'
        pose.header.seq = seq
        pose.pose.position.x = xi
        pose.pose.position.y = y[i]
        pose.pose.position.z = 0
        path.poses.append(pose)
    seq += 1

    print(path)
    path_pub.publish(path)

rospy.init_node('path_node')
path_pub = rospy.Publisher('/path', Path, queue_size=10)
r = rospy.Rate(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [ 3.86600947,  3.80181702,  3.72560205,  3.6376916 ,  3.53846288,
        3.42834168,  3.30780053,  3.17735667,  3.03756983,  2.88903983,
        2.73240402,  2.5683345 ,  2.3975353 ,  2.22073931,  2.03870516,
        1.85221396,  1.66206593,  1.46907699,  1.27407525,  1.07789747,
        0.88138542,  0.68538235,  0.4907293 ,  0.29826151,  0.10880487,
       -0.07682768, -0.25783959, -0.43345415, -0.60291779, -0.76550335]
    
    y = [3.88656062, 4.07229724, 4.25343267, 4.42918964, 4.598814  ,
       4.7615779 , 4.91678291, 5.06376305, 5.20188764, 5.33056399,
       5.44923995, 5.55740628, 5.65459886, 5.74040062, 5.81444339,
       5.87640946, 5.92603293, 5.96310087, 5.98745423, 5.99898849,
       5.99765418, 5.98345701, 5.95645791, 5.91677272, 5.86457174,
       5.80007895, 5.7235711 , 5.63537648, 5.53587353, 5.42548921]
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        cartesian_to_path(x,y)
        r.sleep()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315912/own-nav-path-has-closed-loop-in-rviz/) by [Svyatoslav Mishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/40079/svyatoslav-mishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was mistake with declaration the object of class Path(), it was global, so, path object was not rewrited, path data was appending every cycle of Rate.
correct source:

```
#...
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose

def cartesian_to_path(x, y):
    path = Path()
    path.header.frame_id = 'odom'
    path.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    #...
 #...
```

---

Originally posted by [Svyatoslav Mishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/40079/svyatoslav-mishin/) with karma: 16 on 2019-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0